# Abstract algebra field polynomial division

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let F be a field, let
${h(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_{1}x+a_{0}}$

belongs to F[x],
and let $g(x)=x-1$.

show that $g(x)$ divides $h(x)$ iff ${a_{n}+a_{n-1}+...+a_{1}+a_{0}=0}$.

Can someone help me proving this, please!!

Comment: Did you mean to say $g(x)$ divides $h(x)$ iff $a_n+a_{n-1}+\ldots+a_0=0$?

Comment: I edited it, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarized from Dummit and Foote page 307 (Proposition 9):

> Let $F$ be a field and let $p(x)\in F[x]$. Then $(x-\alpha)$ divides $p(x)$ if and only if $p(\alpha)=0$.

Proof: If $(x-\alpha)$ divides $p(x)$ then we can write $p(x)=q(x)(x-\alpha)$ for some $q(x)\in F[x]$. Then $p(\alpha)=q(\alpha)(\alpha-\alpha)=0$.

For the other direction, suppose $p(\alpha)=0$. Then by the Division Algorithm we have $p(x)=q(x)(x-\alpha)+r$ where $r$ is a constant polynomial. Then since $p(\alpha)=0$, it follows that $r=0$ (show this), and thus $(x-\alpha)$ divides $p(x)$.

Remark: to obtain *your* result, just take $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Dear downvoter: care to explain why this answer is not satisfactory?